# Допустим такой перенос?

Tags: перенос

Скажите, пожалуйста, допустим ли такой перенос: ро-спись? Все ресурсы по переносам дают только вариант *рос-пись,* но мне кажется, что указанный мной вариант тоже не является ошибкой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, так переносить нельзя. Две согласные на стыке обычно разделяют переносом, но это не главное. А главное то, что при переносе *рос-пись* как раз ***разделяются приставка и корень,*** а в вашем варианте С от приставки прилипает к корню второй части. Так делать нельзя.

---

Итак, оказалось, что ***теперь*** можно переносить, как предлагает Александр. Что ж, давайте считать мой ответ консервативным, рассматривающим более строгий подход, характерный для прежних правил.

Comment: Можно указание на источник правила, что нельзя отделять часть приставки?

Comment: См.ссылку в моем ответе.

Comment: @Nektoid: я так думал. Виноват, если ошибался.

Comment: Мне кажется, тут дело не в строгости подхода старых правил, а в том, что теория слога с 1956 года значительно углубилась и не в малой степени изменилась.

Comment: Даже не знаю, мне сложно судить...

Answer (score 2):

**Ро-спись**
Так переносить можно. Правило, изложенное в *§ 119, п. 4 "Правил русской орфографии и пунктуации"*, ныне носит рекомендательный характер (см. [справочник Лопатина, § 217](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=97#pp97)).
Согласно закону восходящей звучности, на конец слога должен приходиться звук с максимальной звучностью. Шкала звучности по убыванию: **4 — гласные, 3 — сонорные, 2 — шумные звонкие, 1 — шумные глухие**. Таким образом, *"о"* обладает бо́льшей звучностью, чем *"с"*, поэтому перенос *"ро-спись"* **допустим**.

Comment: Такой перенос возможен в других словах, где нет приставки.

Comment: @Серж он возможен везде. И по Вашей ссылке (в сноске), и у Лопатина особо оговорены случаи с дроблением приставки.

Answer (score 2):

1. Ресурсы часто дают два варианта переноса слова: ро-спись и рос-пись, например: [https://slogislova.ru/слово-роспись](https://slogislova.ru/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C)  Причем второй вариант обычно считается правильным **в школе.**
2. А в вузах изучается теория, где рассматриваются два варианта **слогового деления.** Слог определяется как произносительный **квант речи**. Он не выражает смысловых связей звуков, как морфемы,  а  характеризуется (1) акустической или (2) артикуляционной слитностью звуков при их произношении.

По одной теории, слог – это один гласный звук или несколько звуков, которые произносятся **одним толчком** выдыхаемого воздуха (лод-ка). По другой теории, слоги строятся по принципу **восходящей звучности** (ло-дка).

Comment: Помнится, я где-то читал о четырёх теориях слога. UPD: да, точно: https://kpfu.ru/docs/F1274724716/Kamalova.L.A.Lekciya._.6..Fonetika.pdf

Comment: Очень может быть, что их четыре, можно при желании  и пятую придумать.  Кроме того,  слоговое деление и перенос – это не одно и то же. Мне наиболее естественной кажется артикуляционный принцип, он и ребенку понятен, и всем остальным пользователям.  Остальные  – для студентов:  они фонетику изучают на первом курсе, чтобы потом сразу же всё забыть.  Людям  же практика нужна,  а для этого  и учебник для 1-го класса вполне подойдет.

Comment: И еще. До падения редуцированных запись была такая: лодъка, пътица. И теперь согласный звук, потерявший "свой" гласный,  приписывается к предыдущему слогу, что вполне логично.

Comment: Не вижу какой-то особой логики в том, что приписывается к предыдущему слогу, а не к следующему.

Comment: А вы постарайтесь увидеть эту логику. Разумно начинать слог с того согласного, после которого стоит полноценный, а не краткий гласный.

Answer (score 1):

Корректно: рос-пись.
Правило таково: при переносе слов с приставками нельзя оставлять в конце строки при приставке начальную часть корня, не составляющую слога.

Неправильно: по-дбить, размах.
Правильно: под-бить, раз-мах.

[Правила переносов](http://new.gramota.ru/biblio/readingroom/rules/141-perenos)

Comment: Всё правильно, только у Александра, наоборот, в начале строки при корне конец приставки.

Comment: Ну и? Я не понял вас, если честно.

Comment: Ну прочитайте своё правило и сравните с моим комментарием. И так и так нельзя, но у автора именно так, как я написал.

Comment: Это правило давно уже в ранге рекомендаций. О чём в Вашей ссылке имеется сноска.

Comment: Артем, наверное, вы имеете в виду другие примеры, которые по ошибке я скопировал. С этими примерами все нормально.

Comment: С примерами-то да — всё нормально. Я просто толкую о разнице отрыва одной последней буквы от приставки (как у автора) и первой от корня (как вы рассматриваете).